# How to sent structure array details to BIN file

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I have a code and my question is how to send structure array information to file and then scan it. I have some functions, but my function Write doens't write correctly to file.

```
typedef struct School
{
    char Lesson[50];
    char TeachersName[50];
    char TeachersLastName[50];
    int Credits;
    int NumberOfStudents;
} School;

void Write(struct School sAmlendraInfor[]);

int main()
{
    School sAmlendraInfor[MAX_SIZE] =  {{"Math","NAME_A","LAST_NAME_A",120,60},
{"History","NAME_B","LAST_NAME_B",60,33}};
    Scan(sAmlendraInfor);
    Print(sAmlendraInfor);
    Write(sAmlendraInfor);
}



void Write(struct School sAmlendraInfor[])
{
    int chars;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("\student.bin", "wb");


    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    chars = fwrite (&sAmlendraInfor, sizeof(School), 1, fp);
    printf("Number of items written to the file: %d\n", chars);

    fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific in what errors you are observing? It is typically difficult to help people in a meaningful way when all we have is "doesn't work". By the way, I see at least 3 major (and some minor) problems with your `Write` function. Which do you want help with?

Comment: @HAL9000 I just have 2 structure values in array and I tried to write whose values into file, but after I try to scan file after write I only got one line with random symbols. So, I can't be more specific about this problem.

Comment: If you want to write more than 1 structure, you should pass an argument to `Write`, telling it how many element there are. The reason you are seeing random symbols in the file is because you are writing the memory content of a struct, rather than serializing it to a human readable format. Writing/Reading raw memory is simple and easy, but not flexible, and it becomes a pain when the data contains pointers, or you need to move the files to a different architecture. If you want to serialize the data, you should look into CSV or JSON.